# iOS NSString Comparison vs. Objective-C Subclassing

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a custom NSObject data structure that I want to give different behaviors.

To implement the various behaviors, is it faster to

1. perform an NSString comparison every time (call this situation X) one of these behaviors may happen (`if ([obj.name isEqualToString:@"...A..."]) ... else if ([obj.name isEqualToString:@"...B..."]) ...`   Then for different situations Y, include only the string comparisons for the names that should trigger in situation Y. `(if ([obj.name isEqualToString:@"...C..."]) ... else if ([obj.name isEqualToString:@"...D..."]) ...`
   or
2. subclass the data structure and overwrite a class method `-(void) doThisAtPointX:..(inputs)..` and call `doThisAtPointX` at all points X where I need the variable behavior, instead of the `NSString` comparison?  In this method, the default implementation would be a NO-OP or blank call, so subclasses that do not trigger at a certain call would still get a method call but no effect, since the calling routine has no idea whether or not the object has custom behavior or not.  So `doThisAtPointX`, `doThisAtPointY`, ..., will always get called at X, Y, Z, on every object, but instead of a string comparison to determine if my object is one of the ones that needs to react, I rely on having a subclass pointer perform either NOOP or non-NOOP behavior when called.

Granted, even for ***Method 2***, at some point I need to do a string comparison to assign the right subclass pointer, but it's only one string comparison at the beginning to get the right custom pointer rather than multiple comparisons every time the custom behavior might be triggered.

For the purposes of this question, we can consider the number of custom behaviors (i.e. string comparisons in ***Method 1***, or number of subclasses in ***Method 2***) to be constant, hovering around 200.  A comparison/possible check for custom behavior would happen about once every 30 seconds in the app.

Comment: Convert the strings to integer (enums) as soon as possible and compare those instead.

Comment: have _you_ tried which way is faster? if no, why not yet?

Comment: Because it takes a lot of time to implement 200 subclasses.  The cost of getting a definitive answer for myself is about a two additional weeks of work.

Comment: Not true.  By that definition, every question would be getting the job done by something else because everything can be verified with enough time.

Comment: Not asking you to test something, asking for an answer to a general question.  Do you see the request "Please test & compare" in my OP? Specify where exactly I violate that. Then show me a better way to word my question, and I will gladly do so, because it is a general and hypothetical topic, not a request to do work.  If you know the answer, you wouldn't need to lift a finger.

Comment: This question is primarily opinion based (notwithstanding the suggestion to try both and profile..), so this is just my opinion, but the "correct" OO approach is method 2. I would use a factory pattern to return the appropriate subclass given the string. It will result in cleaner code and allows you to easily go from 200 subclasses to 201 subclasses by simply implementing the additional class and changing the factory method.  Doing this with method 1 would require multiple changes with corresponding scope for error

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding right, I think the question is comparing performance of:

```
// SingleClass.m

- (void)doSomething {

    if ([self.someProperty isEqualToString:@"A"]) {
        // behavior for A
    } else if ([self.someProperty isEqualToString:@"B"]) {
       // behavior for B
    // and so on, 200 times
```

versus

```
// AbstractClass.m

- (void)doSomething {
}

// SubclassA.m

- (void)doSomething {
    // behavior for A
}

// SubclassB.m

- (void)doSomething {
    // behavior for B
}

// and so on, 200 times
```

The second way is faster.  In the second way, the work of the giant conditional gets done while creating the differentiated instances.  To test this, create two methods, one that does 100 if-else string compares (average case) , and one that doesn't.  I haven't run this test, but I predict the latter method runs in less time.

A few observations:

1. This doesn't consider the human effort involved in building in maintaining 200 subclasses vs. a 200 branch conditional.
2. Nor does it consider the (probably) huge improvement that can be had by mapping a 200 branch string compare to a 200 case switch statement doing int compare.
3. Nor does it contemplate that no choice (on the scale of hundreds, done every 30 secs) will matter at all in terms of user perception.
4. Also worth pointing out that in the subclass approach, changing `someProperty` (`name` in the OP), means morphing the instance.

Comment: Thanks danh. For method 2, I meant to have SubclassA and SubclassB with doSomethingAtX and doSomethingAtY (where in some subclasses, doSomethingAtX may not be overwritten at all because it doesn't do anything at X), but there are different points in the main code where different subclasses execute, so...

Comment: For method 1, I was not thinking of creating a class at all, but rather instead of SubclassA, SubclassB, separate objects etc, just have an NSString, and where it is possible that something *may* execute, instead of calling doSomethingX on every subclass involved, compare the NSString with only the possible behaviors. So say that SubclassA and SubclassC and Subclass Z all overwrite doSomethingAtX, but SubclassB and SubclassD overwrite doSomethingAtY.

Comment: In Method 1, with no subclasses, whenever I hit situation X in maincode, I have the conditional if ([str isEqualToString:@"SubclassA"] || [str isEqualToString:@"SubclassC"] || [str isEqualToString:@"SubclassZ"]) [self doSomething].  The biggest advantage I see in the string approach is the conditionals branch less, since I pre-eliminate the NO-OPs, and the other advantage is I don't need to pass all these variable inputs into the subclass methods (doSomethingAtX/AtY use different inputs), as it is written higher up (in main) & has access to more variables/can see more of the system etc.

Comment: If example is too abstract, I don't mind sharing real code in chat/email, just not publicly since it's for an in-house project. Thanks & sorry for the confusion.